# MySQL Packet Size -- dump -- restore -- Bug or configuration?

Tags: mysql, export, import

I'm taking backups using `mysqldump -u root -p${THEPASSWORD} --max-packet-size=250M db > db.sql` on all my systems and all the databases are being unloaded successfully.

However, when I try to restore the same dump to the same system, I get an error message of `ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 271: MySQL server has gone away` even when I  have set the `max-packet-size` to 1G for both command line and the my.cnf variable. even I have tried to set the runtime variable value on the mysql Server side by logging into the mysql server and setting up the appropriate variable to 1G.

The Question:

How come same mysql server can export a large dataset, which it can't import to itself. What happens to the server when importing the dump that was generated from it.

the dump in question here is around 25G in size.

Thanks

Comment: Check the MySQL server's log files.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`